# How to translate "I have bought some wines and cheeses for my family because they are delicious"?

Tags: grammaire, traduction

> I have bought some wines and cheeses for my family because they are
>   delicious.

I translated it to 
"J'ai achete du vin et du fromage pour ma famile parce que ils sont delicieux"

Is it correct ?

Comment: Yes it is but don't forget the accent on "acheté"

Comment: @LaurentS. can you help me to check again ? Because I changed something in my sentence ( I added "they are delicious.")

Answer (score 3):

You can translate it in different ways, with some nuances:

> J'ai acheté du vin et du fromage pour ma famille parce que c'est délicieux

or:

> J'ai acheté des vins et des fromages pour ma famille parce qu'ils sont délicieux.

or

> J'ai acheté des vins et des fromages pour ma famille parce que c'est délicieux.

In the 1st sentence, you have bought some wine and cheese in undefined quantity but you don't mention a certain kind of cheese or wine. You use then the partitive "du", and it is more coherent then to refer to it as "ce" in the 2nd part of the sentence. It is then a general statement about wine and cheese - wine and cheese is delicious in general, not just the ones you have bought.

In the second sentence, you have bought some specific flavors or brands of wine and cheese (but the plural "vins" and "fromages" implies you have at least 2 different kinds of wine and 2 different pieces of cheese). It is then more coherent to use the pronoun "ils" in the 2nd part. You then state that the specific kinds of wine and cheese you have bought are delicious (but that does not imply that you think ALL other kinds are delicious too).

The 3rd sentence is a bit of a mixed bag: you have bought some specific flavors or kinds of wine and cheese (see 2nd sentence), but you state that you have chosen to buy some wine and cheese (and not eg chocolate) because wine and cheese  in general is delicious - not just the ones you have chosen.

(Note the sentence *J'ai acheté des vins et des fromages pour ma famille parce qu'ils sont délicieux* may sound a bit funnily ambiguous: it may be understood as "because the members of my family are delicious" if the pronoun "ils" is understood as a substitute for "famille". You may want to then say eg "parce ce sont des produits délicieux".)

Comment: Ça dépend du contexte, mais pas sûr qu'on insisterait sur le fait d'acheter : « J'ai pris du vin et du fromage pour ma famille parce que c'est délicieux » me semble plus naturel. L'idée, c'est qu'on évite de parler d'argent et de dépense, en particulier quand il s'agit d'un cadeau.

Answer (score 1):

Meaningwise, yes it is. Anyone will understand that in France.

Now, to the details (spelling errors); the correct spelling would be

> J'ai achet**é** du vin et du fromage pour ma fami**l**le parce **qu'ils** sont d**é**licieux.